# what Egyptian hieroglyph(s) meant/depicted "time"?

Tags: meaning

Does anybody know what Egyptian hieroglyph was used to describe time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "time".

- ***3t*** [image: hieroglyph for 3t] means "instant" or "moment";
- ***88*** [image: hieroglyph for 8][image: hieroglyph for sun][image: hieroglyph for 8] means "eternity";
- ***sp*** [image: hieroglyph for sp] means "time" as an abstract concept.

There are also hieroglyphs for "year", "month", and various other units of time.

(Regarding transliteration, what I write as *3* is the glottal stop or alef, also written *Ꜣ*: /ʔ/; what I write as *8* is Arabic's "emphatic h", also written *ḥ*: /ħ/.)

Comment: thank you so much for your reply. is there somewhere I will be able to read about these and the origin of these symbols?

Comment: @Jeremy A good Egyptian dictionary will have more information on them. Wiktionary is not a bad starting point if you don't have access to other dictionaries: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EA%9C%A3t#Egyptian for example.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, feel free also to upvote or accept it!

Comment: Could '3t' be the real root of Latin 'ad' and Germanic 'at'?

Comment: @amI It's possible that they're related, but unlikely; "at" and "ad" come from the reconstructed PIE root * _h₂éd_ "at, near". Nobody's entirely sure what sounds * _h₂_ or *3* actually were, but it's possible they were both uvulars.